# How to use the "cookies" setting for PhpBrowser in codeception's acceptance.suite.yml?

Tags: php, cookies, cloud9-ide, codeception

I've tried googling this but I wasn't able to find an answer so I'm posting here.

I'm trying out codeception 2.1.5 on Cloud9 IDE using PHP 5.5.9, looking at writing acceptance tests, and configuring my acceptance.suite.yml file.

I'm trying to have a cookie included in the request made by PhpBrowser as described on the [codeception PhpBrowser page](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser#.Vnl1G8ArJcw). I thought I could do this with the "cookies" setting in acceptance.suite.yml.

acceptance.suite.yml

```
# Codeception Test Suite Configuration
#
# Suite for acceptance tests.
# Perform tests in browser using the WebDriver or PhpBrowser.
# If you need both WebDriver and PHPBrowser tests - create a separate suite.

class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: https://dm1-cboudreausf.c9users.io
            cookies: 
                 c9_user_cookie:
                    Name: c9.live.user.sso
                    Value: somevaluehere
                    Path: /
                    Domain: .c9users.io
         - \Helper\Acceptance
```

Here's my HomepageCept.php:

```
<?php 
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('ensure the homepage renders correctly');
$I->amOnPage('/'); 
$I->see('welcome');
```

But when I run my test in debug mode like this:

```
php codecept.phar run --debug
```

I can see that there are no request cookies:

```
Ensure the homepage renders correctly (HomepageCept)
Scenario:
* I am on page "/"

  [Page] /
  [Response] 302
  [Request Cookies] []
  [Response Headers] {"Location":["https://c9users.io/_user_content/authorize?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fdm1-cboudreausf.c9users.io%2F"],"Date":["Mon, 21 Dec 2015 22:38:44 GMT"],"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-BACKEND":["apps-proxy"],"Content-Type":["text/html"]}
  [Redirecting to] https://c9users.io/_user_content/authorize?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fdm1-cboudreausf.c9users.io%2F
```

What is the correct syntax for this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies parameter is not processed by PhpBrowser but passed to Guzzle HTTP Client.

If you run your test and PHP 5.4, then you use Guzzle 5.3, http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/5.3/clients.html?highlight=cookies

`Types: bool / array / GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJarInterface`

I don't know if the format that you used works with Guzzle 5.3, but the key-value pairs should be working

`cookies: 
  'c9.live.user.sso': 'somevaluehere'`

If you run your test on a newer version of PHP, then you probably use Guzzle 6
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#cookies
`You must specify the cookies option as a GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJarInterface or false.`

I see no way cookies option could be working with Guzzle 6, so I raised the issue in Github: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/2653.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, I'm using PHP 5.5.9 on Cloud9 (I'll update my question to include this). It appears codeception 2.1.5 uses Guzzle 6 like you found - which would explain why no matter what syntax I tried to set a cookie, I never saw anything come through. Thank you for opening the issue on github. Let's see how codeception responds there.

Comment: You could use "composer require guzzle 5.3" to make Codeception use older version, if you need this functionality now.

Comment: Thank you. I used the following composer.json and it worked.
    {
        "require": {
            "codeception/codeception": "*",
            "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "5.3"
        }
    }